# Confusion with Fancy indexing (for non-fancy people)

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, indexing, slice

Let's assume a multi-dimensional array

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.random.rand(102,43,35,51)
```

I know that those last dimensions represent a 2D space (35,51) of which I would like to index **a range of rows** of a **column**
Let's say I want to have rows 8 to 30 of column 0
From my understanding of indexing I should call

```
foo[0][0][8::30][0]
```

Knowing my data though (unlike the random data used here), this is not what I expected

I could try this that does work but looks ridiculous

```
foo[0][0][[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30],0]
```

Now from what I can find in [this documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c)  I can also use 
something like:

```
foo[0][0][[8,30],0]
```

which only gives me the values of rows 8 and 30
while this:

```
foo[0][0][[8::30],0]
```

gives an error

```
File "<ipython-input-568-cc49fe1424d1>", line 1
foo[0][0][[8::30],0]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't understand why the :: argument cannot be passed here. What is then a way to indicate a range in your indexing syntax?

So I guess my overall question is what would be the proper pythonic equivalent of this syntax:

```
foo[0][0][[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30],0]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with `foo[0][0][[8::30],0]`. How 'bout `foo[0][0][8::30][0]`?

Comment: have you tried `foo[0, 0, 8:30, 0]`?

Comment: Also note that `::` is part of the extended slice syntax, no need to keep calling it "fancy indexing." `:)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: @OphirCarmi this works indeed thanks!

Comment: @MattBall tried foo[0][0][8::30][0] but what i get seems to not be what i expect. From the values of my dataset the result seems like a row slicing

Comment: @MattBall you are right about slice syntax. Text is now updated
I still don't understand why oo[0][0][8::30][0] doesn't return what i expect

Comment: IIUC how about `foo[0,0,8:30,0]`?

Comment: Slice syntax is `start:stop:step`, so according to your description you need `8:30`, not `8::30`, which means every 30-th item, starting at the 8-th, all the way to the end.

Comment: @Divakar that worked indeed as mentioned also by Ophir Carmi before

Comment: @Jaime I think i might be starting to get it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
foo[0][0][8::30][0]
```

try

```
foo[0, 0, 8:30, 0]
```

The `foo[0][0]` part is the same as `foo[0, 0, :, :]`, selecting a 2d array (35 x 51).  But `foo[0][0][8::30]` selects a subset of those rows

Consider what happens when is use `0::30` on 2d array:

```
In [490]: np.zeros((35,51))[0::30].shape
Out[490]: (2, 51)

In [491]: np.arange(35)[0::30]
Out[491]: array([ 0, 30])
```

The `30` is the `step`, not the `stop` value of the slice.

the last `[0]` then picks the first of those rows.  The end result is the same as `foo[0,0,0,:]`.

It is better, in most cases, to index multiple dimensions with the comma syntax.  And if you want the first 30 rows use `0:30`, not `0::30` (that's basic slicing notation, applicable to lists as well as arrays).

As for:

```
foo[0][0][[8::30],0]
```

simplify it to `x[[8::30], 0]`.  The Python interpreter accepts `[1:2:3, 0]`, translating it to `tuple(slice(1,2,3), 0)` and passing it to a `__getitem__` method.  But the colon syntax is accepted in a very specific context.  The interpreter is treating that inner set of brackets as a list, and colons are not accepted there.

```
foo[0,0,[1,2,3],0]
```

is ok, because the inner brackets are a list, and the numpy `getitem` can handle those.

`numpy` has a tool for converting a slice notation into a list of numbers.  Play with that if it is still confusing:

```
In [495]: np.r_[8:30]
Out[495]: 
array([ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
       25, 26, 27, 28, 29])
In [496]: np.r_[8::30]
Out[496]: array([0])
In [497]: np.r_[8:30:2]
Out[497]: array([ 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28])
```

Comment: Thank for the detailed explanation! Really helped to understand this especially with the `np.r_`  function